# Android Wifi Rssi Value

Tags: android, android-wifi, rssi

I am making an application in which I will create a wifi hotspot using my android device. A hardware will be connected to this hotspot. Now I want to know the RSSI value of this wifi connection on my android device as this value will be used for creating notifications in my android phone. 
Please note that I need to create a hotspot using my android phone.

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to recognize your question

Comment: ` WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid = info.getSSID();
int rssi = info.getRssi(); ` . I have used this but it only works when my android device is connected to an access point. But I want to my android device to act as a access point by creating wifi hotspot and then to read th RSSI value of the connections made to this AP

Answer (score 2):

You get the SSID you are connected to and its RSSI like this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid = info.getSSID();
int rssi = info.getRssi();
```

Comment: This I have already tried. It works fine when my android device is connected to an Access point. But I want to act my android device to act as an Access point by turning on wifi hotspot. And I want to get the RSSI value of the connection between the hardware and my phones hotspot..